# JSON parse error Illegal character for IBM API Connect JSON

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-rest

I tried to call IBM Blumix APIConnect to get JSON. RestTemplate use for that. But I get this error message.

```
"Error while extracting response for type [class x] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\\r, \\n, \\t) is allowed between tokens; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\\r, \\n, \\t) is allowed between tokens\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]",
```

how can i fixed this. I tried the same endpoint with POSTMEN. It shows the correct json.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9UKU_12.4.0/com.ibm.cplex.zos.help/Parameters/topics/APIEncoding.html

Answer (score 0):

change you content type to json
application/json;charset=iso-8859-1

in the body tab on POSTMAN you can choose JSON(application/json) from dropbox

now you can write json on body request.

Comment: I use the restTemplate to call GET request. No Body in that. The response is not accepted by RestTemplate.